# Iphone sdk - Strange behaviour with UITableView and UITableViewCellAccessory

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I am having a strange behaviour loading a table.

The table sometimes loads fine and sometimes load UITableViewCellAccessory's are added to some rows of the last section.

Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath code

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
NSString *enabled= @"1";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}


if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =[section1 objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        return cell;


    }
}       
if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =[section2 objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        return cell;


    }
}       


if(indexPath.section == 2)
{
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Morning Time: %@" , [section3 objectAtIndex:0]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        return cell;


    }
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Afternoon Time: %@" , [section3 objectAtIndex:1]];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        return cell;

    }
}

if(indexPath.section == 3)
{

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =@"Monday";

        if([enabled isEqualToString:[section4 objectAtIndex:0]]){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        return cell;



    }
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =@"Tuesday";

        if([enabled isEqualToString:[section4 objectAtIndex:1]]){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        return cell;


    }
    if(indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =@"Wednesday";

        if([enabled isEqualToString:[section4 objectAtIndex:2]]){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
        return cell;


    }
    if(indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =@"Thursday";

        if([enabled isEqualToString:[section4 objectAtIndex:3]]){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
        return cell;



    }
    if(indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =@"Friday";

        if([enabled isEqualToString:[section4 objectAtIndex:4]]){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
        return cell;



    }
    if(indexPath.row == 5)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =@"Saturday";

        if([enabled isEqualToString:[section4 objectAtIndex:5]]){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
        return cell;



    }
    if(indexPath.row == 6)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =@"Sunday";

        if([enabled isEqualToString:[section4 objectAtIndex:6]]){
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        return cell;



    }


}   
return cell;
```

}

The last row has a UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton, but I have never set up this button to this section and occurs randomly:

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a recycled cell that was previously used for section 2, and hence has a disclosure button.  Since you only change the `accessoryType` if the day is enabled, you never remove the disclosure button if it's not enabled.

Easiest way to fix this is to do:

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
```

right after you dequeue/create the cell.